# I'm trying to confirm my BCH is being held on my trezor

Tags: trezor, bitcoin-cash, firmware

When I go to https://trezor.io/claim-bch/ I'm being told my trezor needs a firmware update. However, I have updated my firmware on wallet.trezor.io. Is there an issue with claiming BCH? If not, why am I being told I need new firmware? My firmware version is 1.5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is now not relevant; on the current website - https://wallet.trezor.io - there is already a firmware, that supports Bitcoin Cash.

Answer (score 0):

TREZOR says that Bcash (Bitcoin Cash) will only be available in [TREZOR Beta Wallet](https://beta-wallet.trezor.io/) for now. They chose this strategy, as they don't want to force a firmware update on users that are not interested in Bcash. Mode details on [Claim your Bcash (BCH) in TREZOR Wallet](https://blog.trezor.io/claim-bcash-bitcoin-cash-bch-bcc-trezor-wallet-f0a810d5864a)